# Xamarin Collectionview Binding Not working

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I have a problem where I am using a collectionview and I am trying to get the bindings to work.
I have tried to set the Height, as I saw in other posts, by setting the miniumheight and heightrequest of every element involved, with no success. I have a listview with a textcell and that is the only way I can get this to work.

Model

```
    [Table("Category")]
    public class Category
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
    public class CategoriesViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; }
        public Command LoadCategoriesCommand { get; }
        public Command AddCategoryCommand { get; }

        public CategoriesViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Categories";
            Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
            LoadCategoriesCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadCategoriesCommand());

            AddCategoryCommand = new Command(OnAddCategory);
        }

        async Task ExecuteLoadCategoriesCommand()
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                Categories.Clear();
                var categories = await DataStore.GetCategoriesAsync();
                foreach (var cat in categories)
                {
                    Categories.Add(cat);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }

        public void OnAppearing()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
        }
```

View

```
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FreeScanner.ViewModels"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:FreeScanner.Models"
             x:Name="BrowseCategoriesPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddCategoryCommand}" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <RefreshView x:DataType="local:CategoriesViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadCategoriesCommand}"
                 IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <CollectionView x:Name="CategoriesListView"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="10" x:DataType="model:Category">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Text="{Binding Name}"
                               FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>  
        </CollectionView>
        <!--<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" 
                  x:Name="CategoriesListView"
                  SelectionMode="None"
                  RowHeight="50">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Category">
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>-->
    </RefreshView>
```

When I debug and hover over the CollectView ItemSource Categories I do see the Count = 1 and I can verify that is correctly loading from the database.

[image: Screenshot of Page]

Comment: if the ListView works, it's probably not a binding issue.  It's more likely the layout engine can't figure out what size your Layout needs to be.  You can easily test this by hardcoding a value in your Label to see if it displays.

Comment: It's not a good idea to have your database model used in the view.

Comment: Yes, I did that per your comment on another thread. I expected to see it print the HC value times the count but nothing showed.

Comment: @neil The new documentation recommended it. It is now it the code that comes with a new project on a tabbed project

Comment: Which documentation recommended it?  Isn't this supposed to be MVVM, not DBVVM.  If you update Category.Name, your view will not be updated because your database class doesn't support INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @Neil I literally just changed the default code to see how it was working, it was like initially. I hope I understood this correctly, maybe I didn't Neil

Comment: If you create a new project, (Tabbed) is what I made. And read the comments and link that in is on the ItemPage I thought it was saying to include it. And it is in the example code. I don't understand it either. Funny enough when I launch the project nothing shows @Neil. And if I remove it, Error reads can't find it in the viewmodel, which the examples don't have it there? I am confused by the example I think

Comment: x:DataType enables compiled bindings for better performance and compile time validation of binding expressions.
      https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings

Comment: And the example has a x:Datatype on the stackLayout

Comment: @Neil so I should put the properties in the Viewmodel with the get _private and SetProperty(_private, value)? @Neil?

Comment: The point of a viewmodel is that it represents and supports the view in the simplest way possible. It may have many more or fewer properties than the data source depending on the views requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=>Try this it's working well

```
public class CategoriesViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
        public Command LoadCategoriesCommand { get; }
        public Command AddCategoryCommand { get; }

        public CategoriesViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Categories";
            
            LoadCategoriesCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadCategoriesCommand());

            AddCategoryCommand = new Command(OnAddCategory);
        }

        async Task ExecuteLoadCategoriesCommand()
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                Categories.Clear();
                var categories = await DataStore.GetCategoriesAsync();
                foreach (var cat in categories)
                {
                    Categories.Add(new Category{Name=cat.Name});
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }

        public void OnAppearing()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
        }
```

=>This is my Xaml

```
<CollectionView x:Name="CourseList"  IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleCourse}" ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}"  >
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout  Orientation="Vertical" Span="2"/>
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout Padding="5" Spacing="-6">
                            <Frame BorderColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=140,Tablet=210}" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="False" Padding="5">
                                <StackLayout Padding="5" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="5">
                                    
                                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="Pic" LoadingDelay="0"
                                                                            Margin="0,5,0,0" WidthRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=60,Tablet=100}"
                                                                   HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=60,Tablet=100}" Source="{Binding ImageURL}"
                                                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent" Aspect="Fill" >
                                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                                            <ffTransformations:CircleTransformation />
                                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                                       
                                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" MaxLines="2" Style="{StaticResource TextDefaultStyle}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Fill"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}" MaxLines="2" Style="{StaticResource TextMicroStyle}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Fill" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                   
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                                Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.CourseListCommand, Source={x:Reference CourseList}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                       
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

Comment: Jasmin, Still nothing for me

Comment: Can I see your XAML please?

Comment: Yes, I have added in my answer please check it.

Comment: Yes, it works. My original code worked also, but The temp phone I was using was in Dark Mode so I couldn't see anything.